# What should be last, cache plugins or CDN plugins?

Tags: joomla-2.5, cache

I'm running several plugins to try to speed up our site and make the load on the server a bit lighter. I've got JotCache and NoNumber Joomla CDN running, along with the template itself compressing some things. It does all appear to be working, but I'm wondering:

Should the CDN or the Cache plugin be last in the order?

Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also running JotCache and NoNumber CDN, I put JotCache last. The reasoning is that we want the CDN substitutions to happen before the caching, that way the CDN plugin only has to run once for each page.